# search-and-replace dialog is now mostly transparent

Tags: visual-studio

I must have accidentally hit a shortcut key or clicked where I shouldn't have...now my search/replace dialog box in my code editor window is mostly transparent.

Anyone know how to make it opaque again?

Comment: I just now increased and decreased the font size, and that "fixed" it.  But surely there's a more official way to set it?